# How to do calculations using a retrieved Mongoose date field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to do some date calculations on a mongoose retrieved data field and running into problems.

My schema:

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String
    },
    dateCreated: {
        type: Date
    },
    dateLastChanged: {
        type: Date
    },
});
```

I retrieve collection data using `User.findById(id, callback)`. Now I need to do some calculations in the result set, as:

```
var now = new Date();
var diff = (now - user.dateLastChanged) / 360000;
console.log('TOKEN AGE:' + diff);
```

Unfortunately I'm getting `NaN` as a `diff` result. I expected to get hours passed between these 2 dates.

I don't know if my JavaScript is wrong or the mongoose has a incompatible type. I'm using Node.js with Express.

Comment: where is `dateLastChanged` coming from?

Comment: from the database,, part of the mongoose schema.

Comment: can you tell me what `console.log(user,dateLastChanged)` returns?